# Extrair vários valores de uma única variavel em python

Tags: python

Se tenho uma única entrada de dados, tenho como retirar vários valores atribuidos a minha variável e derecionalos a outra?

representação:

```
vrvl = int(input("Dia.mês.ano: ))
dia = dia
mes = mes
ano = ano
#entrada == 22.08.17
print("Dia:", dia)
print("Mês:", mes)
print("Ano:", ano)
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenta usar **[split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)**

```
dia, mes, ano = input("Dia.mês.ano:").split('.')
print("Dia:", dia)
print("Mês:", mes)
print("Ano:", ano)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você também poderia usar uma lista para armazenar as informações, algo assim:

```
dia, mes, ano = input("Dia Mês Ano: ").split(' ')
lista = [dia, mes, ano]
```

Poderia facilitar a manipulação dessas informações dependendo dos objetivos do seu código.